# kableExtra generates table code formatted as plain text in final LaTeX file

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

`kableExtra` seems to disrupt the proper formatting of kables in LaTeX when the caption contains certain characters.

`kableExtra::kable` will be formatted properly if no caption is used, or if standard `knitr::kable` is used.

The following code will yield oddly formatted results if `kableExtra` is loaded.

````
---
title: "Mock"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---

```{r header, echo= FALSE, include = FALSE,  warning= FALSE}
library(skimr)
library(knitr)
# library(kableExtra)

resumir <- function(var, unit = "", caption = NULL) {

  if(is.null(caption)) {caption <- deparse(substitute(var))}

  skim_to_wide(var) %>%
    mutate_all(as.numeric) %>% 
    kable(caption = paste0(caption, " (", unit, ")"))

}

mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% 
  rename("NO_CYL" = 'cyl', "PEAK_PERF" = "mpg")

attach(mtcars2)

```


`r resumir(POWER_HRS, unit = "$hours$")`
````

I think I know already what's happening but after all the hassle I went through to find the issue I think it's good if this goes up on SO and someone posts an answer (or I will after a bit).

Comment: If you want us to help, you should post code that produces the problem you have.

Comment: Thank you @user2554330, I did try precisely that for a few hours and will keep trying. If I had been able to replicate it, I think I may have solved it already... I was just posting this in the hope someone may notice something I hadn't.

Comment: A strategy for that is to start with a copy of the full document, and delete as much as you possibly can while still seeing the issue.  Takes time for sure.

Comment: Yesterday in the coding section of the day I took the opposite approach, slowly adding elements to my mock document. I dread knitting the full doc cause it takes a couple of minutes even with caches... which is not long enough to truly focus on something else, but also long enough to lose patience over. Quite frustrating anyway, as problem does not show still. I believe I've tested all the coding parts by now... maybe something in the text? I'll update this once I find something. Totally understand it's on hold.

Answer (score 0):

So, to keep it simple, the problem turned out to be having underscores in the caption. The only solution that has worked is to remove them, which is not overly unreasonable.

````
---
title: "Mock"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---

```{r header, echo= FALSE, include = FALSE,  warning= FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

attach(mtcars)


```


`r  kable(cyl, caption = "Cylinder_No.")`
````

There was a [bug report](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1527) for `knitr` but `knitr` currently works fine.